# If $y'' + f_1(x)y' +f_2(x)y = g(x)$ than $y \in C_{}^{k+2}(I)$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R} $ a non empty Intervall and $f_1,f_2,g \in C_{}^{k} (I)$(*) for a $k \in \mathbb{N}_0 \cup {\infty}$ .If a two times differentiable function $y: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$y'' + f_1(x)y' +f_2(x)y = g(x)$ than $y \in C_{}^{k+2}(I)$.

I see that this statement is clearly true, but i have no idea how i can prove this in formally way.

(*)And for example if $k=0$ is $C^{0}(I) = C(I) $ the set of the continuous function on I

Comment: Move everything but $y''$ to the r.h.s. Is the r.h.s differentiable? What does this say about $y$ being $3$ times differentiable? repeat.

Comment: @uniquesolution So we get:
$y''  = g(x) - f_1(x)y' -f_2(x)y$ and we know by assumption that $y$ is 2 time differentiable. And $g,f_1,f_2$ are continuous but this fact don't imply that there are differentiable. So i don't see why it follows that y'' is 3 times differentiable and how that is related to my problem

Comment: See the answer below, my suggestion has been spelled out to you word by word. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Since  $y′′= g(x)−f_1(x)y′−f_2(x)y$ and all functions on the right hand side are assumed to be  continuously differentiable the left hand side is also continuously differentiable. Therefore $y"$ is continuously differentiable that is $y$ is three times continuously differentiable. Continue this process $k$ times and we get the desired result that $y$ is $k+2$ times continuously differentiable.

Comment: Why should the right right hand side assumed to be continuously differentiable ? We know that $f_1, f_2,g$ are continuously and  $y$ ist differentiable why imply this that $g(x)-f_1(x)y'-f_2(x)y$ is  continuously differentiable?

Comment: Note that  the assumption f1,f2,g∈Ck(I)f1,f2,g∈Ck(I) implies that the right hand side is continuously differentiable.